# What image is used to automate SSIS package deployments to SQL Server through bitbucket cloud?

Tags: sql-server, ssis, bitbucket, devops

I'm trying to automate the deployment of an SSIS package to a SQL Server instance's Integration Service Catalog, using bitbucket cloud pipelines.

Visual Studio based apps are normally fine, as you can just pull down the microsoft/dotnet:sdk image at the top of the .yml and msbuild will do its thing.

SSIS packages however need devenv to build, which means the build as above fails.

I'm hoping someone else has managed to get devops in bitbucket working for SSIS packages and can point me in the right direction for an image that supports devenv builds on Bitbucket cloud.

Comment: +1 Interesting question. I know it is possible to script the deployment of SSRS reports, but not SSIS packages. The current method I use is the isdeploymentwizard.exe - or just deploy from VS.

Comment: There's a host of deployment methods but none of them have the required tools installed on the hosted VS DevOps agent.... except maybe the one I've mentioned in my answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes it is disappointing how the data side is not supported in DevOps.

To generate an .ispac from a .sln on a *Hosted VS2017* build agent, use this command line:

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\Common7\IDE\devenv.com" ./YourSolution.sln /build
```

(I found it on the internet somewhere)

I haven't worked out how to deploy, because you need SSIS libraries installed, which the build agent doesn't have as far as I can tell, and I can't work out how to install them.

My next try is to use `catalog.deploy_project`, which should only need SQL libraries to connect to the SSIS instance

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/deploy-and-execute-ssis-packages-using-stored-procedures?view=sql-server-2014

Here's a powershell script that you should be able to adapt to DevOps:

https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/AssistDeploy/1.3.0.0/Content/Functions%5CPublishSsisIspac.ps1

It doesn't use any integration services libraries. It does use System.Data.SqlClient. This should be on the Hosted VS agent. You should be able to open your ISPAC from your artifacts and use it

Comment: I hadn't considered using catalog.deploy_project - that's a really helpful thought, thanks! I think this will meet the use case, with a two step process using both of the processes you've listed.

Comment: I have a link for deploy_project somewhere (in powershell). I’ll find and post. In the meantime if you get it working please document it as an answer!